# Lag changing background

Tags: android

I have defined a OnTouchListener for a ImageButton. When I touch this ImageButton, among other operations, **I change parent layout's background drawable**, which is a PNG image.

Before, instead of changing the background drawable, I changed the background color of the parent layout and that was done immediately. But now, changing the background image, there is a lag of about half second or a bit less.

I cannot accept this lag, so, what could be the best way to reduce it? As said, the image is a PNG which is the recomended to use, but it's size is about 1.4MB. Could this be the problem?

```
btn_gas.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    /*Change background*/
                    rlayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background1_gas);
                    ...
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    /*Back to default background*/
                    rlayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background1);
                    ...
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
});
```

Comment: You can use selector for such kind of need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved reducing the image size. The image had at first 1440x900 pixel size. After reducing it to 640x400 now there is not lag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/background1_gas"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/background1_gas"
      android:state_focused="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/background1" />
```

Use selector for such kind of need.

Comment: But selector in this case would change imagebutton's drawable, and what I need to change is layout's background drawable.

Comment: You can set it as ImageButton background instead of src.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm not explaining it well. I have a parent layout with some items, among which is the ImageButton. This ImageButton has it's own drawable, but when I touch it, what I need to change is parent layout's background.